# React client not connecting to Symfony API using Nginx

Tags: php, reactjs, symfony, nginx

I have set up an AWS Lightsail instance and I am trying to deploy my Symfony API and React Client which connects to that API.

I can access the React client but the Symfony API is unreachable and it shows a 500 Internal Error.

Here is my Ningx config file:

````
```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name name my_server_ip;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;    

    access_log /var/log/nginx/symfony-project.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/symfony-project-error.log error;

    server_name name my_server_ip;    

    client_max_body_size 100m;

    location /api {
        index index.php;
        root /var/www/html/symfony-project/public;
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location / {
        root /var/www/html/react-project/build;
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        index index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
        try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock; 
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;    
        #fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        #fastcgi_index index.php;include fastcgi_params;  
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;    
    }    

    location ~ /\.(?:ht|git|svn) {
        deny all;
    }  
}

server {
    listen 3000;
    listen [::]:3000;

    server_name name my_server_ip;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;    
}
````

In my Ningx error log file I got this error:

2022/02/04 19:07:34 [error] 5100#5100: *72 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php", client: 93.202.51.115, server: symfony-project, request: "GET /api HTTP/1.1", host: "52.59.39.188"

Any suggestions please, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

In the `location ~ \.php` section this is what my config looks like, and it's working well:

```
location ~ \.php {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

**Note**: if you make any changes to your config be sure to restart nginx and php-fpm:

```sh
service nginx restart
service php8.0-fpm restart
```

Comment: I tried this configuration before but it shows me a 404 error. Thank you anyway :)